# SSL/TLS for Web UI in HiveMQ

Tags: user-interface, ssl, web, hivemq

I am trying to enable ssl connection for Web UI of HiveMQ 3.4.2 on CentOS.
I have changed the config.xml file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hivemq xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../hivemq-config.xsd">
    ...
    <web-ui>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <listeners>
            <https>
                <port>8080</port>
                <bind-address>0.0.0.0</bind-address>
                <tls>
                    <keystore>
                        <path>/home/hivemq/myjks.jks</path>
                        <password>changeme</password>
                        <private-key-password>changeme</private-key-password>
                    </keystore>
                </tls>
            </https>
        </listeners>
        ...
    </web-ui>
    ...
</hivemq>
```

I'm creating self signed certificat with this line:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias hivemq -keystore hivemq.jks -storepass changeme -validity 360 -keysize 2048
```

I recive an error message, if I'm trying to start HiveMQ:

> 2019-03-11 19:19:05,671 WARN  - FAILED SslContextFactory@628bd77e(,): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home
>   (Is a directory)
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home (Is a directory)
>               at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>               at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
>               at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.FileResource.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.CertificateUtils.getKeyStore(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.loadKeyStore(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(Unknown Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory.doStart(Unknown Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(Unknown Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(Unknown Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Unknown Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at et.a.a(Unknown Source)
>               at et.a.a(Unknown Source)
>               at com.hivemq.HiveMQServer.b(Unknown Source)
>               at com.hivemq.HiveMQServer.a(Unknown Source)
>               at com.hivemq.HiveMQServer.main(Unknown Source)
>
> 2019-03-11 19:19:05,672 WARN  - FAILED SslConnectionFactory@2fafa7b5{SSL-HTTP/1.1}:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home (Is a directory)
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home (Is a directory)
>               at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>               at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
>               at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.FileResource.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.CertificateUtils.getKeyStore(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.loadKeyStore(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(Unknown Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory.doStart(Unknown Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(Unknown Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(Unknown Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Unknown Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at et.a.a(Unknown Source)
>               at et.a.a(Unknown Source)
>               at com.hivemq.HiveMQServer.b(Unknown Source)
>               at com.hivemq.HiveMQServer.a(Unknown Source)
>               at com.hivemq.HiveMQServer.main(Unknown Source)
>
> 2019-03-11 19:19:05,672 WARN  - FAILED ServerConnector@181098bf{SSL-HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8443}:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home (Is a directory)
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home (Is a directory)
>               at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>               at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
>               at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.FileResource.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.CertificateUtils.getKeyStore(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.loadKeyStore(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(Unknown Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory.doStart(Unknown Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(Unknown Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(Unknown Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Unknown Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at et.a.a(Unknown Source)
>               at et.a.a(Unknown Source)
>               at com.hivemq.HiveMQServer.b(Unknown Source)
>               at com.hivemq.HiveMQServer.a(Unknown Source)
>               at com.hivemq.HiveMQServer.main(Unknown Source)
>
> 2019-03-11 19:19:05,673 WARN  - FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@632b5c79:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home (Is a directory)
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home (Is a directory)
>               at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>               at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
>               at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.FileResource.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.CertificateUtils.getKeyStore(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.loadKeyStore(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(Unknown Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory.doStart(Unknown Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(Unknown Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(Unknown Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Unknown Source)
>               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at et.a.a(Unknown Source)
>               at et.a.a(Unknown Source)
>               at com.hivemq.HiveMQServer.b(Unknown Source)
>               at com.hivemq.HiveMQServer.a(Unknown Source)
>               at com.hivemq.HiveMQServer.main(Unknown Source)
>
> 2019-03-11 19:19:05,673 ERROR - Not able to start Web UI: /home (Is a directory)

I don't know what is wrong. Can some one help me please.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like that the configuration with the correct path was not saved before starting HiveMQ. Judging by the stack trace your config.xml contains currently only the path "/home" for the keystore.

This should be easily resolved by making sure that your correct path is saved, before starting HiveMQ.

Best regards,

Abdullah from The HiveMQ Team